# Using an If macro to find cell with certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cost sheet with a lot of Macros in it. One of the Macros is to add a new line item to the bottom of the sheet. I want to enter an If code saying that if the item I add starts with the text "Custom " with a space after I want it to find that cell and select it. Below is the code I am trying but it Debugs with Type Mismatch and highlights the Custom = Range("B:B").Value line. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 Dim Custom As String
    Custom = Range("B:B").Value
    If Custom Like "Custom *" Then
    Cells.Find(What:="Custom ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ("Test")
    End If
```

Comment: Remove everything except line which starts with `Cells.Find....` and keep until `....Activate` and tell me if it isn't what you need??

Comment: @KazJaw: My apologies... Just saw your comment. Let me know if you would like to post an answer. I will delete mine.

Comment: let's keep your one... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to use `LIKE` for this. Directly use `.Find` See this example

Note the use of `LookAt:=xlPart`. This will ensure that if there is `"Custom "` anywhere in the cells content, the code will catch it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Custom ", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.Value = "Test"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```